# Unable to cycle through entire Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run this bit of code through a button, this is my first time using VBA, and I am not sure why I am getting this error:

> Run-time error '3021': No current record.

On this line of the code:

```
ConsumerID_1 = rs!CONSUMER_ID
```

The recordset has 26k records, the first time I clicked the button it worked but on re-clicking the error appears.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command23_Click()

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_30days_NoDefaults", dbOpenDynaset)

'1. Start of recordset
'2. Store 1st Consumer ID (v1)
'3. Move to next record
'4. Store 2nd Consumer ID (v2)
'5. Compare both Consumer IDs for a match
'6. If matched Then move to previous record and store repair date (v3), go 
to 8.
'   7. Else Move to next record and loop back to 2.
'8. Move to next record and store call date (v4)
'9. Compare repair date and call date and find the difference between them 
to check If they are within 30 days of each other
'10. If <30 days, move to previous record and check Repeat field boolean 
True/Yes
'11. Move to next record and loop back to 2.

Dim ConsumerID_1 As Long
Dim ConsumerID_2 As Long
Dim RepairDate As Date
Dim CallDate As Date
Dim DiffDate As Long

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF

FirstLoop:
ConsumerID_1 = rs!CONSUMER_ID
rs.MoveNext
ConsumerID_2 = rs!CONSUMER_ID
If ConsumerID_1 = ConsumerID_2 Then
    rs.MovePrevious
    RepairDate = rs!RepairDate
    rs.MoveNext
    CallDate = rs!CsrCallDate
    DiffDate = DateDiff("d", RepairDate, CallDate)
        If DiffDate <= 30 Then
            rs.MovePrevious
            rs.Edit
            rs!RepeatBoolean = True
            rs.Update
            rs.MoveNext
            GoTo FirstLoop
        Else
            rs.MovePrevious
            rs.Edit
            rs!RepeatBoolean = False
            rs.Update
            rs.MoveNext
            GoTo FirstLoop
        End If
Else
    rs.MoveNext
    GoTo FirstLoop
End If

Loop

rs.Close

End Sub
```

Is it because I have not cleared the variables or am I using the wrong type of loop?

**EDIT #1**

[Snapshot of table in current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElV8j.png) and [Snapshot of table in current form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWKEd.png)

Some of the records have been successfully captured while others have been missed out completely.

I will clarify further, I was initially given a data dump, with all records in no particular order. I used a select query and make table query to get this data into a more understandable recordset. The relevant fields are CSR (which is unique with no duplicates), CONSUMER_ID (which is unique to each consumer however there are duplicates since one consumer can have multiple call outs), CsrModel, CsrSerialNumber, CsrCallDate, RepairDate and RepeatBoolean.

I have been told to group the records by three fields: CONSUMER_ID, CsrModel, and CsrSerialNumber. So when you pull up the table, for example, a CONSUMER_ID may be present 3 times along with matching identical CsrModel numbers and CsrSerialNumber. The CSR field for each consumer is in ascending order so that both the CsrCallDate and RepairDate are also in order from old to new. My objective is to loop through each record and check whether the CONSUMER_ID's match first and then if so execute the code to check if the 30 day criteria is met.

My problem at the moment, after testing the code several times, is that it will not capture all the required records, it misses out some for reasons I'm not full comprehending. If I use two recordsets will this solve the issue?

The following is the SQL from the query that made the above table:

```
SELECT tbl_30days_CSR.CONSUMER_ID, tbl_30days_CSR.CSR, 
tbl_30days_CSR.CsrCallDate, tbl_30days_CSR.RepairDate, 
tbl_30days_CSR.CsrModel, tbl_30days_CSR.CsrSerialNumber
FROM tbl_30days_CSR
GROUP BY tbl_30days_CSR.CONSUMER_ID, tbl_30days_CSR.CSR, 
tbl_30days_CSR.CsrCallDate, tbl_30days_CSR.RepairDate, 
tbl_30days_CSR.CsrModel, tbl_30days_CSR.CsrSerialNumber
HAVING (((tbl_30days_CSR.CONSUMER_ID) In (SELECT [CONSUMER_ID] FROM 
[tbl_30days_CSR] As Tmp GROUP BY [CONSUMER_ID] HAVING Count(*)>1 )) AND 
((tbl_30days_CSR.CsrModel) In (SELECT [CsrModel] FROM [tbl_30days_CSR] As 
Tmp GROUP BY [CsrModel] HAVING Count(*)>1 )) AND 
((tbl_30days_CSR.CsrSerialNumber) In (SELECT [CsrSerialNumber] FROM 
[tbl_30days_CSR] As Tmp GROUP BY [CsrSerialNumber] HAVING Count(*)>1 ) And 
(tbl_30days_CSR.CsrSerialNumber)<>565432105 And 
(tbl_30days_CSR.CsrSerialNumber)<>1));
```

**Edit #2**

Current code using Jericho's solution, however still not capturing everything:

```
Private Sub Command26_Click()

'Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstConsumers As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCalls As DAO.Recordset
Dim mssql As String
Dim RepairDate As Date

'Set db = CurrentDb()
' ==============================
' Get a unique list of Consumer_ID's into a RecordSet
' ==============================
mssql = "SELECT tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CONSUMER_ID FROM 
tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2 GROUP BY CONSUMER_ID;"
Set rstConsumers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rstConsumers.EOF
' ==============================
' For each unique Consumer_ID, get the list of Calls in date order
' ==============================
mssql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2 WHERE 
tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CONSUMER_ID = " & rstConsumers("CONSUMER_ID")
mssql = mssql & " ORDER BY tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CSR;"
Set rstCalls = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenDynaset)
Do While Not rstCalls.EOF
    RepairDate = rstCalls("RepairDate")
    rstCalls.MoveNext
    If Not rstCalls.EOF Then
        If DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) <= 30 And 
        DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) >= -30 And 
        DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) = 0 Then
            rstCalls.MovePrevious
            rstCalls.Edit
            rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = True
            rstCalls.Update
        'Else  NOT REQUIRED SINCE DEFUALT IS UNCHECKED (FALSE)
            'rstCalls.MovePrevious
            'rstCalls.Edit
            'rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = False
            'rstCalls.Update
        End If
        rstCalls.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
' ==============================
' After we have processed all of the Calls for this Consumer_ID
' Close the RecordSet for these Calls and loop to the next Consumer_ID
' ==============================
rstCalls.Close
rstConsumers.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rstConsumers.Close
'Set db = Nothing
'db.Close

End Sub
```

**Edit #3**

[Updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36017.png)

**Final Edit #4**

```
Private Sub Command26_Click()

'Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstConsumers As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCalls As DAO.Recordset
Dim mssql As String
Dim RepairDate As Date

'Set db = CurrentDb()
' ==============================
' Get a unique list of Consumer_ID's into a RecordSet
' ==============================
mssql = "SELECT tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CONSUMER_ID FROM 
tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2 GROUP BY CONSUMER_ID;"
Set rstConsumers = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rstConsumers.EOF
' ==============================
' For each unique Consumer_ID, get the list of Calls in date order
' ==============================
mssql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2 WHERE 
tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CONSUMER_ID = " & 
rstConsumers("CONSUMER_ID")
mssql = mssql & " ORDER BY tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2.CSR;"
Set rstCalls = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenDynaset)
Do While Not rstCalls.EOF
    RepairDate = rstCalls("RepairDate")
    rstCalls.MoveNext
    If Not rstCalls.EOF Then
        If DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) <= 30 And 
           DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) >= -30 Then
            rstCalls.MovePrevious
            rstCalls.Edit
            rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = True
            rstCalls.Update
            rstCalls.MoveNext   'MOVED HERE***
        'Else   NOT REQUIRED SINCE DEFUALT IS UNCHECKED (FALSE)
            'rstCalls.MovePrevious
            'rstCalls.Edit
            'rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = False
            'rstCalls.Update
        End If
        rstCalls.MoveNext 'MOVED INSIDE THE IF STATEMENT***
    End If
Loop
' ==============================
' After we have processed all of the Calls for this Consumer_ID
' Close the RecordSet for these Calls and loop to the next Consumer_ID
' ==============================
rstCalls.Close
rstConsumers.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Finished looping through records."

rstConsumers.Close
'Set db = Nothing
'db.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What line in the code throws this error? Note: You can use debug to step through the code line by line.

Comment: before movefirst, check if you actually have any record in the recordset.

Comment: It's this line: ConsumerID_1 = rs!CONSUMER_ID.
The recordset has 26k records.
It ran once when I clicked the button but when I try again the error appears

Comment: I have edited the original post with further details

Comment: I have a feeling it is starting at the end of the recordset for some reason, the ConsumerID_1 variable holds the last ID number from the recordset when it throws the error

Comment: Looking at your code it seems like this could be done with pure SQL rather than jumping back and forth in the recordset - which is likely to give you incorrect results at some point (don't ask my why as I haven't thought about that bit - but telling it to go to the previous record without being REALLY specific about what the previous record is sounds like a recipe for disaster eventually). To me it looks like your code is trying to checking to see if the repair was carried out within 30 days of the call, if it was then set the `RepeatBoolean` field to TRUE, otherwise set it to FALSE.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have found that it has not correctly set the Boolean to TRUE for all the records that have met the condition but only some. When you say pure SQL do you mean I should write a query def within the code? Could you please provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: To add further detail, the data is from a table where records are grouped together by the CONSUMER_ID, Model and SerialNumber. The code above checks whether the CONSUMER_ID matches then takes the repair date from the first record and call date from the record below (2nd record) to check if they are within 30 days of each other, there are cases where the repair date falls before call date and vice versa (so it's essentially a check between -30 and 30).

Comment: If it is within 30 days then the first record will check its Boolean as TRUE, then it should point to the second record and check whether the CONSUMER_ID matches with the third record's, if not the second record's BOOLEAN will remain unchecked. This will loop till the end of the recordset and is implemented through a button. The recordset can get larger as more repairs are added, the button will be clicked every time this 30 day report is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be a different way to achieve your intended results, the crux of the problem with your current code is that by using the `GoTo FirstLoop` commands, you are bypassing the EOF checking that the `Do Until rs.EOF` line is supposed to perform.  Therefore, your code IS actually looping through all the records, and one of your `rs.MoveNext` lines is causing the Recordset to get to EOF, and your `GoTo FirstLoop` takes you directly to a line of code trying to retrieve a value that does not exist, therefore the error is generated.

Your `Do` loop is a loop, and there is no need to artificially force looping with your `GoTo` statements.

I have modified your loop to allow the EOF checking to do it's job and exit the loop when you run out of records.

I would expect your original code to run differently based on there being an odd or even number of records in your RecordSet. But I also think your original code would have been an infinite loop until the error occurs because I see no way for your original code to exit the loop.  All three execution paths (your various `If Then Else` statements) contain a `GoTo FirstLoop`, so it appears your code could only have ended in an error when EOF was finally reached.

```
' ==============================
' The original rs.MoveFirst line is not needed before the loop
' and would actually generate an error if there
' happened to be zero (0) records returned in the RecordSet
' ==============================

Do While Not rs.EOF
    ConsumerID_1 = rs!CONSUMER_ID
    rs.MoveNext
    ' ==============================
    ' Always check for EOF after a MoveNext
    ' before retrieving a value
    ' ==============================
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ConsumerID_2 = rs!CONSUMER_ID

        If ConsumerID_1 = ConsumerID_2 Then
            rs.MovePrevious
            RepairDate = rs!RepairDate
            rs.MoveNext
            ' ==============================
            ' Since we have already performed a MoveNext
            ' and MovePrevious, we know these two records
            ' exist and it is safe to exclude the EOF check
            ' ==============================
            CallDate = rs!CsrCallDate
            DiffDate = DateDiff("d", RepairDate, CallDate)
            If DiffDate <= 30 Then
                rs.MovePrevious
                rs.Edit
                rs!RepeatBoolean = True
                rs.Update
            Else
                rs.MovePrevious
                rs.Edit
                rs!RepeatBoolean = False
                rs.Update
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
rs.Close
```

I have also removed some of your redundant `rs.MoveNext` commands and consolidated them into a single line that all three cases that existed before will still execute.

This code will perform the same actions you had in the original code, and it will not error out when there are odd numbers of records in your table.

**Update #1**

Based on additional questions in the comments by the OP, the following code should provide the intended results.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstConsumers As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCalls As DAO.Recordset
Dim mssql As String
Dim RepairDate As Date

Set db = CurrentDb()
' ==============================
' Get a unique list of Consumer_ID's into a RecordSet
' ==============================
mssql = "SELECT CONSUMER_ID FROM tbl_30days_NoDefaults GROUP BY CONSUMER_ID;"
Set rstConsumers = db.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rstConsumers.EOF
    ' ==============================
    ' For each unique Consumer_ID, get the list of Calls in date order
    ' ==============================
    mssql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_30days_NoDefaults WHERE CONSUMER_ID = " & rstConsumers("CONSUMER_ID")
    mssql = mssql & " ORDER BY CsrCallDate;"
    Set rstCalls = db.OpenRecordset(mssql, dbOpenDynaset)
    Do While Not rstCalls.EOF
        RepairDate = rstCalls("RepairDate")
        rstCalls.MoveNext
        If Not rstCalls.EOF Then
            If DateDiff("d", RepairDate, rstCalls("CsrCallDate")) <= 30 Then
                rstCalls.MovePrevious
                rstCalls.Edit
                rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = True
                rstCalls.Update
            Else
                rstCalls.MovePrevious
                rstCalls.Edit
                rstCalls("RepeatBoolean") = False
                rstCalls.Update
            End If
            rstCalls.MoveNext
        End If
    Loop
    ' ==============================
    ' After we have processed all of the Calls for this Consumer_ID
    ' Close the RecordSet for these Calls and loop to the next Consumer_ID
    ' ==============================
    rstCalls.Close
    rstConsumers.MoveNext
Loop
rstConsumers.Close
Set db = Nothing
db.Close
```

Comment: The DateDiff function does not seem to pick up dates that have a difference of 0, i.e. the call date and repair date being on the same day. I have tried including DateDiff = 0 in the logical arguement with no success. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: There are also some actual results which are being missed out completely, I think my way of doing this is not very efficient nor does it seem to capture all of the intended records. Would doing this through SQL, albeit I'm not sure how, be a better way? Darren, above, suggest using pure SQL. If there is any resource you could direct me to so I can try and learn how to myself that would be helpful as I don't want to keep bothering people about this.

Comment: @Env67 You are now asking a different question than the original post. Based on your comments, the issue is about HOW you are pulling and organizing your recordset. From what we can see in your code, you are just pulling records in "table" order, therefore there is no guarantee that all Calls for a particular Consumer are grouped together, nor in date order to allow your code to properly determine if two Calls for the same Consumer are within 30 days.  Short answer, your stated goal cannot be accomplished in SQL alone, but it can be accomplished with two RecordSets and minor code tweaks.

Comment: @Envy67 First RecodeSet would be a unique list of each ConsumerID, using a GROUP BY query. Then I would loop through each ConsumerID, pulling all of the Call records for that ConsumerID in CallDate order.  Now your code to determine if Call "A" is within 30 days of Repair "B" would be much more likely to find and correctly stamp all of the "Repeat" Calls.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will clarify further, I was initially given a data dump, with all records in no particular order. I used a select query and make table query to get this data into a more understandable recordset. The relevant fields are CSR (which is the unique and the primary key), CONSUMER_ID (which is unique to each consumer however there are duplicates since one consumer can have multiple call outs), CsrModel, CsrSerialNumber, CsrCallDate, RepairDate and RepeatBoolean.

Comment: I have been told to group the records by three fields: CONSUMER_ID, CsrModel, and CsrSerialNumber. So when you pull up the table, for example, a CONSUMER_ID may present 3 times along with matching identical CsrModel numbers and CsrSerialNumber. The CSR field for each consumer is in ascending order so that both the CsrCallDate and RepairDate are also in order from old to new. My objective is to loop through each record and check whether the CONSUMER_ID's match first and then if so execute the code to check if the 30 day criteria is met.

Comment: My problem at the moment, after testing the code several times, is that it will not capture all the required records, it misses out some for reasons I'm not full comprehending. If I use two recordsets will this solve the issue?

Comment: I have tried implementing the code from your update #1. I have a question regarding this though, after it has looped through everything is it saving the results to the new tables or the original one? I have not noticed any changes in the original table under the RepeatBoolean field, nor is there any new tables in the objects pane.

Comment: My code sample operates on solely on the `tbl_30days_NoDefaults` table, and if a records is within the 30 days, the `RepeatBoolean` field is updated to True, so that is what you should see.  No new tables are created.  You can enhance the GROUP BY query in my code to also group on Model and SerialNumber if that is a requirement for the 30 day checking, but then we would need to change the 2nd recordset to pull by ConsumerID, Model & SerialNumber so that it just looks at those Calls for a customer for that particular Model/SerialNumber item.

Comment: I have got this to be accepted:
`mssql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_30days_CSR_NoDefaultsOr1s_v2 WHERE CONSUMER_ID = " & rstConsumers("CONSUMER_ID") & _
    mssql = mssql & " WHERE CsrModel = " & rstConsumers("CsrModel") & _
    mssql = mssql & " WHERE CsrSerialNumber = " & rstConsumers("CsrSerialNumber") & _
    mssql = mssql & " ORDER BY CSR;"`
But now I get an error stating: Run-time error '3078': The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'False'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Comment: Hard to tell the issue in your comment due to the extra ampersand and underscore symbols that may or may not be in your real code.  I would also guess that the Model and SerialNumber fields are strings, and therefore need to be quote delimited to work properly in the query.  I would recommend using the Access query designer to create a test query with all 3 criteria to make the query work, then get the SQL from the query designer and adapt that into the code so that it has proper syntax and quoting of string values.

Comment: I am going to give that a go now. In the mean time, could you please kindly explain why this code, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWKEd.png), does not cycle through each record in the recordset properly. To me the logic appears to be correct so it should start with first record and go through each subsequent one in order?

Comment: I have now implemented your code correctly from the Update #1. However it does not check all of the required `Repeat Boolean` fields for the recordset. Any ideas why? It has captured more than my original code but not everything, I will post the entire code under **Edit #2**.

Comment: In Edit #2, and your screenshot, your `If` statement only works for cases where the DateDiff is equal to 0.  Since you are using AND for each case, the difference must be <= 30 AND >= -30 AND = 0, therefore 0 (zero) is the only value that would ever meet all three criteria and cause `RepeatBoolean` to be set to True.  You don't need the 0 case, just the <= 30 AND >= -30.

Comment: Also, since you removed the `Else` section, you now need to move the MoveNext into the `If` section, otherwise you will skip checking of records, which you have already stated is happening.  Think of the 2 logic cases: **1** Look at Rec 1, Look at Rec 2, If within 30, Move back and Update Rec 1, Move to Rec 2 and Loop.  **2** Look at Rec 1, Look at Rec 2, If NOT within 30, stay on Rec 2 and Loop.

Comment: Please see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36017.png). Let me know if you meant move that inside, OR just add another one inside and leave that as is

Comment: Ok I left that one and just added another inside the `If` statement and it seems to be working now. Let me know if that was what you intended as well. Otherwise I think we're set. You are the best Jericho, I cannot thank you enough! I have learnt a tonne during this exercise, you've been a great help. I hope you have a great weekend! :)

Comment: Yes, your screenshot is correct.  You moved the `rstCalls.MoveNext` into the `If` statement and commented it out in the old location.  If this helped you, please do me the favor of marking my Answer as Accepted.  Thanks.